# Listen gem and monitoring for filesystem changes

Tags: ruby, filesystems

I've just come across the [listen](https://github.com/guard/listen) gem which watches for file system events (or polls) and can execute your ruby code when a file changes or is added.

It looks really nice, but if I need to catch *any* change/addition to the files in a directory, is there a way for me to catch any files that were changed since the script was last run?

ie. is there any way to have `Listen` work with persistence?

Comment: I'm afraid you have to do this yourself (save last known state of files)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev how to save the last known state of files?

Answer (score 0):

If directory change events order matters, then you probably cannot get that order after your script has stopped working, as it lost and cannot be retrieved from the filesystem.

Otherwise I would utilize git repo to collect changes after previous commit, making commits before script stops working.

Answer (score 0):

Try on console with below command to fix the issue

```
echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p
```